# How strings differ from massive(array) of chars in Pascal?

Tags: arrays, string, char, pascal

I have a problem. Why I can't assign the value of strings to strings, but with chars it works. Why ^^^^^^? Where's string? Why There's the a[i]?
Is it because internal representation of strings and chars?

```
 program massive.pas;
 
 type
         chars = array [1..255] of char;
 
 var
         s,s1: string;
         ch1,ch2: chars;
         i: integer;
 
 begin
         s1 := '';
         s := 'abrakadabra';
         for i := 1 to 5 do
         begin
                s1[i] := s[i];
                writeln(s1[i],#10,'^^^',s1,'^^^')
         end;
         ch2 := '';
         ch1 := 'abrakadabra';
         for i := 1 to 5 do   
         begin 
                ch2[i] := ch1[i]
                writeln(ch2[i])
         end;    
         writeln('%%%',ch2,'%%%');
         for i := 1 to 5 do 
                writeln('&&&',s1[i],'&&&');
 end.
```

**Output*

```
a
^^^^^^
b
^^^^^^
r
^^^^^^
a
^^^^^^
k
^^^^^^
a
b
r
a
k
%%%abrak%%%
&&&a&&&
&&&b&&&
&&&r&&&
&&&a&&&
&&&k&&&
```

Comment: The data type `string` as you are using there is not standardized. You may wanna indicate which compiler you are using. Can you tell us what you wanted to do, what code you first wrote? If you want to assign a value _to_ an `array[1..255] of char` you will need to provide an “assignment-compatible” value. For arrays this means a sequence of _exactly_ 255 `char` values. However, the other way round usually works, because there are various (non-standard) algorithms out there accommodating for too many (or too few) `char` values, e.g. silently clipping/discarding (or inserting spaces at the end).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main difference between `type chars = Array[1..255] of Char` and `String` is that a `chars` array has a fixed length, while the string has a dynamic length.

You did not say which compiler you use, but I do think that the `String` type is what in some Pascal editions is called a `ShortString`, with a max length of 255 chars. The space for 255 chars is preallocated and the structure includes a length field, that keeps track of assigned length of the string.

In your example, you assign `s1 := '';` in other words the length is set to zero. Then you do a mistake in the `for loop` in assigning `s1[i] := s[i];` **without setting the length of s1**.

Subsequent reading of `s1` always return an empty string as the length field is 0.

If you would assign the characters to the string, e.g. as:

```
for i := 1 to 5 do
begin
  SetLength(s1, Length(s1)+1);
  s1[i] := s[i];
  writeln(s1[i],#10,'^^^',s1,'^^^');
end;
```

then the result would be what you originally expected.
Still better to set the length to the final 5 before the `for loop`.

Of course there are other solutions too. One is to not set the length at all, but to concatenate the string in the loop and let it handle the length field by itself:

```
for i := 1 to 5 do
begin
  s1 := s1 + s[i];
  writeln(s1[i],#10,'^^^',s1,'^^^');
end;
```

---

Edit 24.12.2021:

In a comment you said: *But I still don't understand, why, when i wrote s1[1] in the for loop, all worked?*

...and presumably refer to this code just before `end.`:

```
for i := 1 to 5 do 
  writeln('&&&',s1[i],'&&&');
```

We need to look at the memory layout and know that the first byte of the memory allocated to `s1` is the length of the string. It can be referred to as `s[0]`. Subsequent bytes hold the characters that make up the stored string and they can be referred to as s[1]..s[n].

The first byte was set to 0 when you wrote (in the very beginning):

```
s1 := '';
// memory content:
 0 
|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_| ...
```

Then you added the characters to `s1` by manipulating the memory directly when you wrote in the first `for` loop:

```
s1[i] := s[i];
// content after 5 characters
 0 a b r a k
|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_| ...
```

Because you did not use concatenation (or adjusted the length while you added the characters) the length is still 0.

Then at the end in the last loop, you fetch the characters again by accessing the memory directly, and get the result you do, seemingly correct, but badly misusing the string structure.

Comment: But  I still don't understand, why, when i wrote s1[1] in the for loop, all worked?

Comment: Your problem is related to how you operate on `s1`, so let's focus on that. The memory used for `s1` has a constant size 256 bytes, and since it is a global variable it is never freed during program execution. Otherwise your comment is correct, but just to reformulate:  Interpretation of the content depends on the length byte, s[0]. If it is 0, the string is considered empty (no matter what the other bytes contain). If s[0] has a value 1 .. 255, then that many characters are considered from s[1] forward.